# Extract string parts that are separated with commas

Tags: c#

I need to extract a string into 3 different variables.

The input from the user will be in this format `13,G,true`.
I want to store the number in an integer, the "G" in a character and "true" into a string.

But I don't know how to specify the comma location so the characters before or after the comma can be stored in another variable.
I'm not allowed to use the `LastIndexOf` method.

Comment: can you use String.Split?

Comment: Use `string.Split` and use the result array. If you're parsing csv, remember there are several csv parsers available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string msg = "13,G,true";
var myArray = msg.Split(",");

// parse the elements
int number;
if (!Int32.TryParse(myArray[0], out number) throw new ArgumentException("Whrong input format for number");
string letter = myArray[1];
string b = myArry[2];

// or also with a boolean instead
bool b;
if (!Int32.TryParse(myArray[2], out b) throw new ArgumentException("Whrong input format for boolean");
```

Comment: this answer isn't complete ("I want to store the number in a int, the G in a char and true into a string.")

Comment: "Can someone help me to extract a string into 3 different variables." - this is what he needed help for to be able to do the things you described, so technically the answer is complete.

Comment: works but I had to use Split(',')  because Split(",") was causing errors in VisualStudio

Comment: @Budapest the overload accepting a `string` instead of `char[]` exists in .NET 5 onwards, so I guess you're using some version of .net Framework.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tokens = str.Split(",");         //Splits to string[] by comma
var first = int32.Parse(tokens[0]);  //Converts first string to int
var second = tokens[1][0];           //Gets first char of the second string
var third = tokens[2];
```

But be aware, that you also need to validate the input

Comment: This is the better answer, but you might explain a little bit more

Comment: added some more comments

Answer (score 1):

use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx)

```
string str='13,G,true';
string[] strArr=str.Split(',');

int32 n=0,intres=0;
char[] charres = new char[1];
string strres="";
if(!Int32.TryParse(strArr[0], out n))
{
intres=n;
}
if(strArr[0].length>0)
{
charres[0]=(strArr[1].toString())[0];
}
strres=strArr[2];


    //you'll get 13 in strArr[0]
    //you'll get Gin strArr[1]
    //you'll get true in strArr[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need method `String.Split('char')`. This method splits string using specified char.

```
    string str = "13,G,true";
    var arrayOfStrings=str.Split(',');

    int number = int.Parse(arrayOfStrings[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// original input
string line = "13,G,true";

//  splitting the string based on a character. this gives us
// ["13", "G", "true"]
string[] split = line.Split(',');

// now we parse them based on their type
int a = int.Parse(split[0]);
char b = split[1][0];
string c = split[2];
```

If what you are parsing is CSV data, I would check out CSV parsing libraries related to your language. For C#, Nuget.org has a few good ones.